# Open/Close Chuck (Clamp/unclamp) with ThincAPI

Tags: okuma

I need to control the clamp and unclamp of the lathe on an LB3000 using Thinc API. I've gone through the documentation and it looks like I can set a lot of chuck specific variables, but I don't see anything for clamping/unclamping the chuck itself. Thanks.

Comment: You can't command the chuck via the API.  Give us some more details about what you're trying to do.  There might be some other way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several things which effect the safety of the machine that cannot be controlled via the standard API, chuck clamp / unclamp being one of them.

The only way to control the chuck via API is by using the **IO Variables Option** `Part # :8303` and hard-wiring the appropriate signals yourself.

Alternatively, **Robot Interface Type D** `(5A5-8269-10)` will allow access to those signals and more via a network interface, the [Anybus](https://www.anybus.com/overview) X-gateway. An application could connect to this gateway and control the desired signals that way.